# Dragging Image in CKEditor PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, primefaces, ckeditor, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I am trying to upload image in CKEditor with image2 plugin.It is wokring fine when I am uploading it by 'send it to server' button but drag and drop of images is not working.

Below is Version Detail:

```
- Primefaces 6.0
- Ckeditor 4.9.1
- JSF 2.2
```

**Config.js**

```
 CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config){
//  config.timestamp='ABCD';
    config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles=false;
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles=false;
    config.allowedContent=true;
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl='#{request.contextPath}/CKEditorGetImageServlet';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'CKEditorUploadServlet';
    //config.filebrowserUploadMethod = "form";
    config.uploadUrl='CKEditorUploadServlet';
    config.extraPlugins = 'image2';
    };
```

**Upload Servlet:**

```
public class CKEditorUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String ERROR_FILE_UPLOAD = "An error occurred to the file upload process.";
    private static final String ERROR_NO_FILE_UPLOAD = "No file is present for upload process.";
    private static final String ERROR_INVALID_CALLBACK = "Invalid callback.";
    private static final String CKEDITOR_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    private static final String CKEDITOR_HEADER_NAME = "Cache-Control";
    private static final String CKEDITOR_HEADER_VALUE = "no-cache";

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\d]*");
    private String errorMessage = "";
    public CKEditorUploadServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType(CKEDITOR_CONTENT_TYPE);
        response.setHeader(CKEDITOR_HEADER_NAME, CKEDITOR_HEADER_VALUE);

        final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        final ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List fileItems = null;
        Iterator itr = null;
        FileItem fi = null;
        File file = null;
        String contentType = "";
        byte[] content;
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);
        System.out.println(id);
        final PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        UploadBean bean = (UploadBean) getServletContext().getAttribute("uploadBean");
        if (bean == null) {
            bean = new UploadBean();
            getServletContext().setAttribute("uploadBean", bean);
        }
        try {
            /*final List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            if (!items.isEmpty() && items.get(0) != null) {
                System.out.println("Content "+((DiskFileItem) items.get(0)).get());
                System.out.println("Content Type "+((DiskFileItem) items.get(0)).getContentType());
                System.out.println("Name "+((DiskFileItem) items.get(0)).getName());
            } else {
                //No file to Upload
            }*/


            fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            itr = fileItems.iterator();
            while ( itr.hasNext () ) 
            {
                fi = (FileItem)itr.next();

                if ( !fi.isFormField () )   
                {
                    String fileName = fi.getName();
                    System.out.println("FileName "+fileName);
                    String ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1,fileName.length());
                    boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
                    contentType = fi.getContentType();
                    content = fi.get();
                    bean.setContent(fi.get());
                    long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();

                    if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 )
                    {
                        file = new File("D:\\Document" + "\\" + id + "." + ext) ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        file = new File("D:\\Document\\" + "\\" + id + "." + ext) ;
                    }

                    fi.write( file ) ;
                }
            }
            bean.setId(id);
            bean.setContentType(contentType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            fileItems = null;
            itr = null;
            fi = null;
        }
     // CKEditorFuncNum Is the location to display when the callback
       // String callback = request.getParameter("CKEditorFuncNum");
       String callback ="1";
        System.out.println("Callback "+callback);
        // verify if the callback contains only digits and letters in order to
        // avoid vulnerability on parsing parameter
        if (!PATTERN.matcher(callback).matches()) {
            System.out.println("Patten not matches");
            callback = "";
            errorMessage = ERROR_INVALID_CALLBACK;
        }
        final String pathToFile = request.getContextPath()
                + "/CKEditorGetImageServlet?imageId=" + bean.getId();
        System.out.println("Path to File "+pathToFile);
        out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction("
                + callback + ",'" + pathToFile + "','" + errorMessage + "')");
        out.println("// ]]></script>");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

**GetImage Servlet**

```
public class CKEditorGetImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String ERROR_FILE_DOWNLOAD = "An error occured when trying to get the image with id:";
    private static final String IMAGE_PARAMETER_NAME = "imageId";
    private static final long CACHE_AGE_MILISECONDS_TWO_WEEKS = 1209600000;
    private static final String CKEDITOR_CONTENT_EXPIRE = "Expires";
    private static final String CKEDITOR_CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
    private static final String CKEDITOR_CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
    private static final String CKEDITOR_CONTENT_DISPOSITION = "Content-Disposition";
    private static final String CKEDITOR_CONTENT_DISPOSITION_VALUE = "inline; filename=\"";
    private static final String CKEDITOR_HEADER_NAME = "Cache-Control";

    public CKEditorGetImageServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        UploadBean bean = (UploadBean) getServletContext().getAttribute("uploadBean");
        final byte[] rb = bean.getContent();
        System.out.println("Inside get Image Servlet "+rb);
        System.out.println("Content Type "+bean.getContentType());
        final long expiry = new Date().getTime()
                + CACHE_AGE_MILISECONDS_TWO_WEEKS;
        response.setDateHeader(CKEDITOR_CONTENT_EXPIRE, expiry);
        response.setHeader(CKEDITOR_HEADER_NAME, "max-age="
                + CACHE_AGE_MILISECONDS_TWO_WEEKS);
        response.setHeader(CKEDITOR_CONTENT_TYPE,
                bean.getContentType());
        response.setHeader(CKEDITOR_CONTENT_LENGTH,
                String.valueOf(rb.length));
        response.setHeader(
                CKEDITOR_CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                CKEDITOR_CONTENT_DISPOSITION_VALUE
                        + bean.getName() + "\"");
        response.getOutputStream().write(rb, 0, rb.length);
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    }
```

As per the [Official Documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_upload.html) of ckeditor we need to write the xhr code at editor level and also at server level which I am not able to get. Could you please help me out in achieving the same.

Comment: Are you using the PrimeFaces Extensions CKEditor component or just raw CKEditor in your project?

Comment: @Melloware using the primefaces extension CKEditor...

Comment: OK I don't think its quite so easy the way the component works to just add your own plugins. See this forum post: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=48585

Comment: @Melloware... Checked the link..But if you see the official link of ckeditor posted in the question; we need to send some json response for dragging the image..but I am not able to get that how to pass the json responce to the callback of ckeditor...

Comment: Like I said without some custom hacking of the PFE component I don't think you will be able to do this.